# lines between cells of multirow

Tags: multicolumn

I don't need lines between multirows and multicoulmns.

Here is my MWE:

```
\usepackage{multirow}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{table}[h]  
    \centering  
    \begin{tabular}{clc}  
        \hline  
        \textbf{Suhu Helm ($ ^{o} $C}) & \textbf{HIC} &\textbf{ Waktu (ms)}\\  
        \hline  
        \multirow{3}{*}{$ -20^{o}$C } & \multicolumn{1}{l}{904.38}  
        & \multicolumn{1}{l}{12} \\\cline{2-3}  
        & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1112.07} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{9.5} \\\cline{2-3}  
        & \multicolumn{1}{l}{833.66} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{9.6} \\\cline{2-3}     
        \hline  
        \multirow{2}{*}{$ 50^{o} $C} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{591.21}  
        & \multicolumn{1}{l}{11}   
        \\\cline{2-3}  
        & \multicolumn{1}{l}{595.24} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{11.8} \\  
    \cline{2-3}  
    \hline  
    \end{tabular}  
    \vspace{ -.5 mm}  
    \caption{xxx}  
    \label{tab:xxx}  
\end{table}  
\end{document}
```

how to remove all the short lines between rows?

Comment: The short lines are triggered by the `\cline` commands, all you need is to remove them.

Comment: but it brings error and conflict with \multicolumn command

Comment: OK, I posted an answer, which confirms that removing the `\clines` does *not* bring errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short lines are triggered by the \cline commands, all you need is to do is to remove them. (I also used the opportunity to write the temperatures using the siunitx package.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage[detect-weight]{siunitx}
\begin{document}  
\begin{table}[h]  
    \centering  
    \begin{tabular}{clc}  
        \hline  
        \textbf{\boldmath Suhu Helm (\si{\degreeCelsius})} & \textbf{HIC} &\textbf{ Waktu (ms)}\\  
        \hline  
        \multirow{3}{*}{$ -20\si{\degreeCelsius}$ } & \multicolumn{1}{l}{904.38}  
        & \multicolumn{1}{l}{12} \\%\cline{2-3}  
        & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1112.07} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{9.5} \\%\cline{2-3}  
        & \multicolumn{1}{l}{833.66} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{9.6} \\%\cline{2-3}     
        \hline  
        \multirow{2}{*}{$ 50\si{\degreeCelsius}$} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{591.21}  
        & \multicolumn{1}{l}{11}   
        \\%\cline{2-3}  
        & \multicolumn{1}{l}{595.24} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{11.8} \\  
    %\cline{2-3}  
    \hline  
    \end{tabular}  
    \vspace{ -.5 mm}  
    \caption{xxx}  
    \label{tab:xxx}  
\end{table}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

And the same output can be generated by the somewhat simpler code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage[detect-weight]{siunitx}
\begin{document}  
\begin{table}[h]  
    \centering  
    \begin{tabular}{cll}  
        \hline  
        \textbf{\boldmath Suhu Helm (\si{\degreeCelsius})} & \textbf{HIC} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Waktu (ms)}}\\  
        \hline  
        \multirow{3}{*}{$ -20\si{\degreeCelsius}$ } & 904.38  & 12 \\
        & 1112.07 & 9.5 \\
        & 833.66 & 9.6 \\
        \hline  
        \multirow{2}{*}{$ 50\si{\degreeCelsius}$} & 591.21  & 11  \\
        & 595.24 & 11.8 \\  
    \hline  
    \end{tabular}  
    \vspace{ -.5 mm}  
    \caption{xxx}  
    \label{tab:xxx}  
\end{table}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes, thank you. I put the % before the lines break \\

Answer (score 3):

you may like this look of the table:

[image]

for it i use packages `booktabs` for horizontal lines, `siunitx` for `S` column type, which enable number aligning at decimal points and for used units, and `caption` for formatting captions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{cS[table-format=4.2]
                 S[table-format=2.1]}
    \toprule
\textbf{Suhu Helm (\si{\degreeCelsius}})
    & \textbf{HIC}  & \textbf{Waktu (ms)}   \\
        \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\SI{-20}{\degreeCelsius}}
    & 904.38        & 12                    \\
    & 1112.07       & 9.5                   \\
    & 833.66        & 9.6                   \\
        \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{\SI{50}{\degreeCelsius}}
    & 591.21        & 11                    \\
    & 595.24        & 11.8                  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{xxx}
\label{tab:xxx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**addendum:**
consider [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot) comment below and making table content more consistent with removing units for temperature in the first column and use `tablenum` for align numbers in `multirow` cells. also now the column headers in `S` columns are horizontal centered:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage[detect-weight]{siunitx} % <--- changed
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{c
                S[table-format=4.2]
                S[table-format=2.1]}
    \toprule
\textbf{Suhu Helm (\si{\degreeCelsius}})
    & {\textbf{HIC}}  & \textbf{Waktu (\si{ms})} \\ % <--- changed
        \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\tablenum{-20}} % <--- changed
    & 904.38        & 12                    \\
    & 1112.07       & 9.5                   \\
    & 833.66        & 9.6                   \\
        \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{\tablenum{50}} % <--- changed
    & 591.21        & 11                    \\
    & 595.24        & 11.8                  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{xxx}
\label{tab:xxx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice! (+1) If you load siunitx as `\usepackage[detect-weight]{siunitx}` like I do it would be probably perfect.

Comment: @marmot, is now better? at least table is more consistent better formatted :-). thank you very much!